# Windows 7 connection to Samba drive does not refresh sometimes

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, samba

System:

- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
- Samba 4.1.6
- Client: Windows 7

I have a drive on Win 7 mapped to an Ubuntu Samba share. Sometimes when I create one or more new files in Ubuntu, I cannot see the new file for 5-10 minutes in the Windows file explorer. Doing Refresh in the File Explorer does not show the new files either. After 5-10 minutes the file explorer seems to do an auto refresh, but in order to do my work I really need to see the files and open them in windows now. (I need to use Excel on my client to open the files on Ubuntu.)

How do I fix this?

Is there a way to force samba to send a refresh signal to Windows? Because I can't seem to get Windows to refresh  the Samba file share list at all.

I'm not real good at Windows networking so if you need more information let me know how to get it and I'll get it for you.

Thanks.